# How to make a infinity ScrollView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

I need to make a horizontal infinity scrollview, but I don't know how to. This is my code:

```
string[] array1 = { "hotel", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b" };
string[] array = new string[20];
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout
{Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,BackgroundColor = Color.Goldenrod,HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,};
Content = new ScrollView{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,Content = stackLayout,
};
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++){
    foreach (var na in array1){
        stackLayout.Children.Add (new Button{ Text = na,});
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look on this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5000/scrolling-listviews-which-get-data-as-needed

Answer (score 2):

**ListView example:**

use ListView.ItemAppearing, for example:

```
var listView = new ListView { ... };

listView.ItemAppearing += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var items = listView.ItemsSource as IList;

    if (items == null
        || items.Count == 0)
        return;

    if (e.Item != items[items.Count - 1])
        return;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The end of the list, load more!");
};
```

---

**ScrollView example:**

```
var scrollView = new ScrollView { ... };

double y = 0;
scrollView.Scrolled += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var item = sender as ScrollView;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    // TODO: remove when bug will be fixed
    // https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59555/scrollview-position-resets-after-resizing-layout-when-running-on-ios
    // https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33385
    // https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43947
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(e.ScrollY) < Double.Epsilon && y > 15)
        {
            await item.ScrollToAsync(0, y, false);
            return;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(item.ScrollY) > Double.Epsilon)
            y = item.ScrollY;
    }

    var scrollingSpace = item.ContentSize.Height - item.Height;

    if (scrollingSpace <= e.ScrollY)
    {
        // use variable for single call, for example if a == false then do something else ignore

        Debug.WriteLine("Loading more ...");
    }
};
```